# Identifying Keys in Database

Tags: key, rdbms

I know the concept of all the keys used in database which include

```
    Super Key
    Candidate key
    Primary key
    Foreign Key
    Surrogate key
```

and some others also. 
My question is that in daily life examples how to correctly identify the above keys from the tabel?

Are there any tips or tricks to remember and use those to differentiate between above keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All DBMSs provide a catalog or similar means of viewing the constraints applied to a table. At minimum the constraints will usually tell you what the candidate keys, primary keys and foreign keys are. Superkey just means any set of attributes that includes a candidate key.

A key is deemed to be a surrogate usually if it is not derived from or used in the business domain outside the database. In other words it is a matter of semantics and is not something you can expect to determine just from looking at a database table.

Note that foreign keys and superkeys are not types of keys. A superkey means a superset of a key. A foreign key means a set of attributes that participates in a referential constraint referencing a candidate key in another table.